# Inserting new data to dataframe with Date index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, indexing

I have a DF like below with Date value as Index

[image]

I have the 6 values in an array and i have added 6 more values to the same array like:
[image]

Now i need to append the whole 12 values to the same array with new Date index value like below:

[image]

When i try to set the value using **test['value'] = new_values** , it is giving the below error:

**ValueError: Length of values (18) does not match length of index (12)**

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question how exactly you're getting the error you mentioned because you didn't show how you created the DataFrame and the arrays.

It's unusual to resize a DF by simply reassigning a single column, which should sound natural to you if you think about how other columns should behave in that situation, in the case where a DF has those. Instead, to resize a DF we usually use one of the specialized functions `pd.concat`, `pd.DataFrame.merge` or `pd.DataFrame.join`.

I'd approach this situation using `pd.concat`; more specifically creating a new DataFrame with *just the new values and index* and concatenating it with the old one.

---

### Recreating the scenario

Here's an attempt to recreate something similar to your starting point; i.e. the initial DF.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

init_index = np.arange(
    np.datetime64("2021-07"),
    np.datetime64("2022"),
    np.timedelta64(1, "M")
)
init_values = np.random.rand(6, 1)

init_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=values,
    index=index,
    columns=["values"]
)

# >>> init_df
#               values
# 2021-07-01  0.002215
# 2021-08-01  0.064340
# 2021-09-01  0.595143
# 2021-10-01  0.822837
# 2021-11-01  0.568886
# 2021-12-01  0.382716
```

And here's the same attempt at recreating your `new_values` array. I'm assuming, from the image you included, that it's not a simple list of values, but a list of lists of values, each containing a single value (i.e. a 2-dimensional array whose shape is `(6, 1)`).

```py
new_values = np.concatenate((init_df["values"], np.random.rand(6,1)))

# >>> all_values
# array([[0.00221483],
#        [0.0643404 ],
#        [0.59514306],
#        [0.82283698],
#        [0.56888584],
#        [0.38271593],
#        [0.23964758],
#        [0.90354089],
#        [0.12688775],
#        [0.53930331],
#        [0.99087057],
#        [0.12583731]])
```

Hopefully that's close enough to what you're working with.

---

### Actual solution

For my approach, we create a new DF with just the new data and the new dates:

```
all_values = new_values
new_values = all_values[7:]
new_index = np.arange(
    np.datetime64("2021"),
    np.datetime64("2021-07"),
    np.timedelta64(1, "M")
)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=new_values,
    index=new_index,
    columns=["values"]
)

# >>> new_df
#               values
# 2021-01-01  0.239648
# 2021-02-01  0.903541
# 2021-03-01  0.126888
# 2021-04-01  0.539303
# 2021-05-01  0.990871
# 2021-06-01  0.125837
```

And then concatenate both DFs using `pd.concat`:

```py
final_df = pd.concat([init_df, new_df])

# >>> final_df
#               values
# 2021-07-01  0.002215
# 2021-08-01  0.064340
# 2021-09-01  0.595143
# 2021-10-01  0.822837
# 2021-11-01  0.568886
# 2021-12-01  0.382716
# 2021-01-01  0.239648
# 2021-02-01  0.903541
# 2021-03-01  0.126888
# 2021-04-01  0.539303
# 2021-05-01  0.990871
# 2021-06-01  0.125837
```